# Flutter doesn't navigate page when register success

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to write the code when register success the system navigate to home page. I success to save data to database and the response status is 200, but still doesn't navigate to home page.

**This the code register_page.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    AuthProvider authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);

    handleRegister() async {

      print('handleRegister() called');
      if (await authProvider.register(
          name: nameController.text,
          username: usernameController.text,
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text)) {
        print('register() returned true');
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      } else {
        print('register() returned false');
      }
    }    
    Widget button(){
      return Container(
        height: 50,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: handleRegister,
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: primaryColor,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
              )
          ),
          child: Text("Sign Up", style: primaryTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: medium
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

...
```

**This the code authservice.dart**

```
class AuthService {
  String baseUrl = "http://192.168.100.229:8000/api";

  Future<UserModel> register(
      {required String name,
      required String username,
      required String email,
      required String password}) async {
    var url = '$baseUrl/register';
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    var body = jsonEncode({
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    });

    var response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: body);

    log('code ${response.statusCode} ');
    log('status : ${response.statusCode == 200? true : false}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data['user']);
      user.token = data['token_type'] + " " + data['access_token'];
      log("register success");
      return user;
    } else {
      log("register fail");
      throw Exception("register failed");
    }
  }
```

**This the code authprovider.dart**

```
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late UserModel _user;

  UserModel get user => _user;

  set user(UserModel user) {
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> register(
      {required String name,
      required String username,
      required String email,
      required String password}) async {
    try {
      UserModel user = await AuthService().register(
          name: name, username: username, email: email, password: password);

      _user = user;

      log("auth provider true");
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      log("auth provider false", error: e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**This the console log**

```
I/flutter ( 6788): handleRegister() called
I/flutter ( 6788): register() returned false
[log] auth provider false
      type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Even auth provider return false, the data still save in database but doesn't navigate to home page.
How to fix that problem?

Comment: Any error you are getting in console?

Comment: Yeah there is error, please check my update post

Answer (score 1):

did you register this "/home" route? and I suggest you put some print statements like this:

```
 void  handleRegister() async{ 
    print('handleRegister() called'); 
    if(await authProvider.register(name: nameController.text, 
    username: usernameController.text,
     email: emailController.text, 
    password: passwordController.text )){ 
    print('register() returned true');
     Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home'); 
    } else {
     print('register() returned false'); 
   } }
```

and then check which printed.

Comment: hii, please check my latest post, I've been edited